# MemTest86, 5 errors, what do they mean?

Tags: memory, memtest86+, memory-error

Alright guys, I've been having this problem with my PC lately where it will freeze suddenly, no Blue screen, it just stops. It's been a nonstop issue, so I decided to do some testing to find out what it could be. First I tested my graphics cards with furmark, but they held up surprisingly well. Then I tried Prime95. I ran it on "blend" and got a lock up in less than a minute. I tried again under "Large FFT" and got a hang in around 30 minutes or so. Ran the last test with "Small FFT" and it ran for 2 hours with no hang. I'm far from an expert, so I thought that maybe it was a memory. I got Memtest86 pro and left it to do its work. I woke up the next morning while it was about to end its test on the third pass and found that it did in fact run into a few errors.

So, here is all the information I was able to gather. Can you guys even give me a inkling on what this could possibly mean? Is it in fact the memory? Maybe the motherboard? I don't know and I could really use the help here. This PC has been running fine for 2 years and now it's starting to act up.

[RAM/SyS information](http://pastebin.com/YACjmzDZ), [Image of MemTest error](https://i.imgur.com/Ks8COys.png)

Additional Info: MB:MSI 990FXA-GD80, PSU: Antec HCG-750, GPU: 2x EVGA GTX 480

I hope this stuff helps.

EDIT: Thank you guys for all o the suggestions. Sadly I found what the problem was. I noticed that the processor was acting funnier than usual. Hitting CPU usage 99% one second then down to 0% the next. A few weeks before this entire thing was happening, I noticed the CPU was getting a little too hot than normal over 60C while browsing web. So I decided that maybe I should check the thermal paste..

The entire processor is fused to the heatsink. Sigh, that's the last time I trust the thermal paste the manufacture supplies... Yeah, so now I need to get that replaced. Again, thanks for all the help. I was hoping it wasn't the processor, but this pretty much confirms it..

Comment: You now need to test your modules one at a time to determine which one is broken. If none are, it may be the motherboard or CPU (contains memory controller).

Comment: reduce the RAM speed from 1600/800 MHz to 1333/667MHz and look if this "fixes" it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is a single address where error happens, and its position, it is possible that there is either an error in the first stick, or there might possibly be an error in MB somwhere pertaining to first slot.

What I would do, is test the memory again while changing the position of sticks.

If error happens again in the same position, it is probable there is an MB error, you might get by by using lower memory in non-faulty slots (if your MB supports not having a stick in slot 1).

If error happens in a different position, but similarly close under a multiple of 8000, it is probable that there is an error in this stick. You'll do best by changing it (again, you might get by on lower memory in the meantime)

Comment: Because memory is interleaved in multi-channel operation, memory addresses cannot be translated that easily.

Comment: Hmm, you are probably right. But I think the general point is still valid, if the address changes it is probably the sticks, if it stays, it's probably the board.

Comment: only install one memory stick, test separately. You probably have a bad stick.